# Запись вызова глобальных методов или свойств

Tags: javascript

Изучаю js и возник такой вопрос, как лучше вызывать методы или использовать свойства, которые находятся в глобальной области видимости: `window.method` или просто `method`? Ясно, что вторая форма записи короче, но вдруг первая читабельней или браузер как-то лучше это переваривает? Скажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: window.method - так практически редко пишут, за исключением случаев, когда необходимо достучаться до какого-либо свойства window. Если к примеру у вас есть метод foo лучше его так и вызывать foo(). Так код чище выглядит. Но конечно, есть случай когда, нужно вызывать window.method это при iframeMessaging, CrossDomainMessaging И тд, а в обычной жизни используйте первый вариант